# ACF not showing

Tags: functions, theme-development, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I have a (weird) issue - can't get the ACF field to work on my page. I have a simple `text_field` and it shows on the `Homepage` page section:

ACF settings:
[image]

---

Homepage settings (when I refresh the panel it shows `Lorem ipsum` so it's saved in the databse):
[image]

And in my `index.php` page I have:

```
<?php
  $hero = the_field('hero_title');
  /* tried also  */
  /* $hero = get_field('text_field'); */

  echo '<h1>'.$hero.'</h1>';
?>
```

Where it shows the blank `<h1></h1>` on my page:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? I also tried with `group` type and I have the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`the_field()` function shows the value and it doesn't get/return anything. Like `the_title()` and other template tags starting with `the_`.

It means that:

This line prints the value and `$hero` variable is empty.

```
$hero = the_field('hero_title');
```

This line prints only `<h1>` tags.

```
echo '<h1>'.$hero.'</h1>';
```

What you want is:

```
echo '<h1>' . get_field('hero_title') . '</h1>';
```

Comment: I tried but it also returns the blank value - `<?php echo '<h1>Title: ' . get_field('hero_title') . '</h1>'; ?>` where the string `Title` is shown.

Comment: So most probably you set it to different post and get it for different post. `echo get_field('hero_title');` should work like a charm.

Comment: But I'm not using a post - it's a single page theme. I have only one page - `Homepage` and the ACF is set to it.

Comment: Update - well this is weird -> if I use ACF rules `Page type` to `Front page` it works, but if I use `Page` to `Homepage` it doesn't?

Comment: It is not weird at all. ACF fields (like all custom fields) are assigned to some post object (pages are posts too). If you use static page as front page, then that page is stored as global $post and `the_field` will get custom fields from that post. If you use Homepage, then global `$post` will contain some post, so you'll be getting custom fields from that post...

Comment: It makes more sense now. Thanks for clarifying that up.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$hero = get_field('hero_title');
```

Instead of

```
$hero = the_field('hero_title');
```